# Compute new matrix derterminant when only two rows change

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have a too large matrix $A$ and I know its determinant denoted by $\det(A)$. Suppose that I update only two rows in $A$ and I need the new determinant. Is it a way to find simply this new derterminant using the old, the new rows and the old determinant?

As the matrix is too large, it will be computationnally intensive if I should compute the new determinant using *det()* function in a software. In addition, I will do this task many times. SO it will be greatfull a have a way to compute the new determinant more simply.

An idea?

Comment: You might not be able to do what you are looking for in general. Changing(updating) an entire row can the determinant drastically. I think you need more information like the relation between the new rows entries to that of the old ones.

Comment: You could when calculating the determinant the first time use [Laplacian Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) and keep track of the determinants of the minors.  At that point, you can use those determinants and the values of the entries of each row for a simple calculation each time you need to modify the rows and calculate the new determinant.  Depending on how the software calculates the determinant in the first place, it might not even be too much more costly to do for the first step.